# Stack Level too deep with method_added ruby

Tags: ruby, module, hook

I have created a module to hook methods before a method call in a class :

```
module Hooks

def self.included(base)
 base.send :extend, ClassMethods
end


module ClassMethods
  # everytime we add a method to the class we check if we must redifine it
  def method_added(method)
    if @hooker_before.present? && @methods_to_hook_before.include?(method)
      hooked_method = instance_method(@hooker_before)
      @methods_to_hook_before.each do |method_name|
        begin
          method_to_hook = instance_method(method_name)
        rescue NameError => e
          return
        end
        define_method(method_name) do |*args, &block|
          hooked_method.bind(self).call
          method_to_hook.bind(self).(*args, &block) ## your old code in the method of the class
        end
      end
     end
   end

  def before(*methods_to_hooks, hookers)
   @methods_to_hook_before = methods_to_hooks
   @hooker_before = hookers[:call]
  end
 end
end
```

I have included the module in one of my class :

```
require_relative 'hooks'

class Block
  include Indentation
  include Hooks
  attr_accessor :file, :indent
  before :generate, call: :indent
  # after  :generate, call: :write_end

  def initialize(file, indent=nil)
    self.file = file
    self.indent = indent
  end

  def generate
    yield
  end
end
```

this Block class is parent to another class that is implementing its own version of the generate method and that is actually implemented.

When my code is running method_added is actually called with method :generate as argument in some kind of infinite loop. I can't figure out why method_added is caught in this infinite loop. Do you know what's wrong with this code ?
Here's a link to the full code :
[link to code on github](https://github.com/davidgeismar/test-automation/tree/master/lib/tasks)

Comment: The tiniest of points: you can write `base.send :extend, ClassMethods` as simply `base.extend ClassMethods`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've caused an infinite recursion because you're calling `define_method` inside `method_added`. The stack trace (which you haven't provided unfortunately) should show this.

A slightly ugly workaround to resolve this could be to explicitly set a variable (e.g. `@_adding_a_method`) and use it as a guard clause for `method_added`:

```
module ClassMethods
  def method_added(method)
    return if @_adding_a_method

    if @hooker_before.present? && @methods_to_hook_before.include?(method)
      # ...

      @_adding_a_method = true
      define_method(method_name) do |*args, &block|
        # ...
      end
      @_adding_a_method = false

      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

**However**, taking a step back, I'm not really sure what this module is trying to achieve. Couldn't you just achieve this with [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend) instead of this meta-programming?

This code reminds me of what you might find in an old Ruby 1.8/1.9 tutorial on advanced meta-programming techniques; `Module#prepend` makes such workarounds redundant for the most part.

Comment: An alternative to the `@_adding_a_method` option is to remove the method name from `@methods_to_hook_before` before calling `define_method`. Instead of `@methods_to_hook_before.each do |method_name|`, use something like `while method_name = @methods_to_hook_before.shift`